# Given 2 data frames search for matching value and return value in second data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Given 2 data frames like the link example, I need to add to df1 the "index income" from df2. I need to search by the df1 combined key in df2 and if there is a match return the value into a new column in df1. There is not an equal number of instances in df1 and df2 and there are about 700 rows in df1 1000 rows in df2.

I was able to do this in excel with a vlookup but I am trying to apply it to python code now.

[image: Data Frame images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='combind_key')
```

This (`left` join) will give you all the records of `df1` and matching records from `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-do-a-vlookup-in-python-using-pandas/

Here is an answer using joins. I modified my df2 to only include useful columns then used pandas left join.

```
Left_join = pd.merge(df,  
                     zip_df,  
                     on ='State County',  
                     how ='left')
```